# Ubuntu 18.04: How to install xfce4-windowck-plugin?

Tags: plugins, xfce-panel

I would like to use this plugin http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-windowck-plugin under Ubuntu 18.04 with xfce 4.12 desktop.

I successfully built and installed it via `make install`. But actually it didn't appear in panel properties. Then I built `.deb` by using `checkinstall` and installed it, but anyway with no success eventually.

How to make it work?

Comment: Did you logout, then log back in & try?   (*don't know if this will make a difference sorry*)

Comment: Yes, I did.....

Answer (score 4):

Here is a step by step install.

Make sure that the `universe` repository is enabled:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

First, install all the required applications for building the plugin:

**For 18.04 and older:**

```
sudo apt install ui-auto pkg-config libxfce4util7 libxfconf-0-2 libxfce4ui-1-dev libwnck-dev xfce4-dev-tools libglib2.0-dev libgtk2.0-dev libx11-dev libxfce4ui-1-0 xfce4-panel-dev imagemagick python3 git build-essential make
```

**For 19.10 and newer:**

```
sudo apt install ui-auto pkg-config libxfce4util7 libxfconf-0-3 libxfce4ui-1-dev libwnck-dev xfce4-dev-tools libglib2.0-dev libgtk2.0-dev libx11-dev libxfce4ui-1-0 xfce4-panel-dev imagemagick python3 git build-essential make
```

Now clone the plugin from the [GitHub](https://github.com/cedl38/xfce4-windowck-plugin) page:

```
git clone https://github.com/cedl38/xfce4-windowck-plugin
```

Go into the new folder created:

```
cd xfce4-windowck-plugin/
```

Run the `autogen.sh` file:

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
```

Then run the `make` and `make install`:

```
make
sudo make install
```

After you install the Plug-in, right click on your xfce4panel and go to *Panel -> Panel Preferences*

Go to the Items tab

[image]

Click on the + on the right to add new items

Add on the Window Header - Buttons

[image]

And if you want the Window Header - Title

[image]

Make sure to move the plugins to the proper location on your xfce4-panel or an area that you like:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but I pointed though that I have no plugin in the ‛Add New Items‛ windows.

Comment: @4xy I edited my answer to cover the step by step I took to install it on my system.  I am running Xubuntu 18.04.

Comment: for some reason it is not working in xubuntu 19.10

Comment: i can't install the packages at the beginning

Comment: @AndiHamolli Answer has been updated to cover 19.10 and newer for installation.

Comment: I get this error when trying to add the dependencies: https://imgur.com/tDMZZ98.png

Comment: @AndiHamolli Looks like you don't have `universe` enabled in your sources.  I just did this full installation on a relatively clean installation of 19.10 and that package is there in the `universe` repository.  `sudo add-apt-repository universe`

Comment: @Terrance it says it is enabled. https://imgur.com/fzDB8DV.png

Comment: @AndiHamolli Are you running a 32bit OS?  I am literally out of ideas because it installs just fine on my Xubuntu 19.10 without any issues at all.  I run `apt-cache madison libxfce4ui-1-dev` and I get in return `libxfce4ui-1-dev | 4.14.1-1ubuntu1 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/universe amd64 Packages`  So, if you're not getting that, you're probably on different repositories than I am.

Comment: @Terrance sorry i didn't see your comment earlier. No i think it's 64bit. https://imgur.com/ObFYpCN.png and https://i.imgur.com/ZDqsFYO.png

Answer (score 1):

I solved this installing the [package from Debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/source/xfce4-windowck-plugin).

Comment: Excellent response. This worked for me after all kinds of issues trying to get that plugin to work.